# PHP data to xml

Tags: php, xml

I have the following code that creates and downloads an xml formatted page.

My issue is when this is viewed in a browser etc I get the xml tree view that i am after, but when i open the page in notepad etc i get it all on one line.

How can i get this to output the file so that it is done as a proper xml tree within notepad etc

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="itunes_' . $_SESSION['xmlfilename'] . '.xml"'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
require_once 'inc/config.php';
require 'class.itunesxmlcls.php';
$d      =   new iTunesXML();
echo $d->CreateItunesXML($_SESSION['update']['id']);
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Use `"\n"` and `"\t"` for output format

Comment: thanks for this i have tried these and they just show up as text

Comment: Make sure you are use double quotes " (not single quote ') with \n and \t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`DOMDocument`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to format it for you by setting the [`formatOutput`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput) flag to `true` before you load the XML, like so:

```
$d   = new iTunesXML();
$xml = $d->CreateItunesXML($_SESSION['update']['id']);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->loadXML( $xml);

echo $doc->saveXML();
```